# how to fill an <li> in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a `<ul>` with data-role="listview" attribute.  For the `<li>` elements, i would like to have a `<div>`, within the `<li>`, that covers the main contents in the `<li>`, and when a person swipes to the right, the `<div>` animates sliding right, revealing the contents underneath div.

My problem is that when I add the div to the `<li>` element, i cant get the `<div>` to cover the `<li>` element.  Even if i set a style of `style: height=100%`, the div seems only to take up about 2/3 of the `<li>` elements space.

Comment: check padding spacing and margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your DIV element to a list-item like so:

HTML --

```
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li data-icon="grid"><a href="#">This is normal content.</a><div class="cover-div">Swipe to Uncover</div></li>
        <li data-icon="grid"><a href="#">This is normal content.</a><div class="cover-div">Swipe to Uncover</div></li>
        <li data-icon="grid"><a href="#">This is normal content.</a><div class="cover-div">Swipe to Uncover</div></li>
        <li data-icon="grid"><a href="#">This is normal content.</a><div class="cover-div">Swipe to Uncover</div></li>
        <li data-icon="grid"><a href="#">This is normal content.</a><div class="cover-div">Swipe to Uncover</div></li>
    </ul>
```

This creates the following output after jQuery Mobile initializes the list-view:

```
<li data-icon="grid" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c">
    <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
        <div class="ui-btn-text">
            <a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">This is normal content.</a>
            <div class="cover-div">Swipe to Uncover</div>
        </div>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grid ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Then you can add positioning and background-styling to the element:

CSS --

```
.cover-div {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    z-index    : 2;
    background : #000;
    background : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color      : #fff;
}​
```

And finally you can detect the swipe events on the "cover" DIVs and animate the element off-screen:

JS --

```
//when a page is initialized by jQuery Mobile, we'll do our own initialization
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {

    //find all the `.cover-div` elements on this page and bind to swipe left/right events for the elements
    $(this).find('.cover-div').bind('swipeleft swiperight', function (event) {

        //if the user swiped to the left then animate the DIV to the left
        if (event.type == 'swipeleft') {
            $(this).stop().animate({ left : '-100%' }, 250);

        //otherwise animate the DIV to the right
        } else {
            $(this).stop().animate({ left : '100%' }, 250);
        }
    });
});
​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pmqDf/1/